# Node.js and PostgresSQL with Express(insert Query)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

I've written a code to fetch the data from postgres database using express and NODE.js. the database is connected with the backend code but still it is showing error in json format. Please check the code and error that I got:
Error is like: 
`{
  "name": "error",
  "length": 120,
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "code": "42703",
  "position": "60",
  "file": "src\\backend\\parser\\parse_relation.c",
  "line": "2892",
  "routine": "errorMissingColumn"
}`

the code that I written is :

```
pg.connect(connectionString, function(err, client, done) {
        if (err) {
            console.error("Not able to get Connection " + err);
            res.status(400).send(err);
        } else {
            console.log("Connected.!");
        }

        // Insert Data in logintable query
        const
        insertQuery = {
            // give the query a unique name
            name : 'insert-user-details',
            text : 'INSERT INTO "testSchema".logintable (id, name) VALUES (03, "Anything")',
        }

        client.query(insertQuery, function(err, result) {
            done(); // closing the connection;
            if (err) {
                console.error("\nError : " + err);
                res.status(400).send(err);
            } else {
                console.log("1 record inserted");
                res.status(200).send(result.rows); // this line returns only a
                                                    // table data in json
                                                    // format.
                // res.status(200).send(result); // this line returns the rows
                // also with the table and field information.
            }
        });
```

Comment: Can you try this way?
text : "INSERT INTO 'testSchema'.logintable (id, name) VALUES (03, 'Anything')"

Comment: Well I tried it and it actually throws an exception: Please check.:


`Error : error: syntax error at or near "'testSchema'"
_http_outgoing.js:494
    throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');`

Comment: Oh! I think you can keep the below query template strings and form it.
     `INSERT INTO "testSchema".logintable (id, name) VALUES (03, 'Anything')`

Comment: Prefer a tool like [knex](https://knexjs.org/) instead of raw queries.

Comment: Quotes are not needed for schema name. Can you provide the output of `\dt` and `\dn` in postgres client?

Comment: well I tried from postgress client with the same query and it works. Please check the attached commands.

`testDatabase=# INSERT INTO "testSchema".loginTable (id,name) VALUES (03, 'Anything');
INSERT 0 1
testDatabase=# select * from "testSchema".logintable;
 id |   name
----+----------
  1 | Sumit
  2 | Anything
  3 | Anything
(3 rows)`

Comment: @S.D. Sequelize is good.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer of the above and it got worked.
check here:

```
//Insert Query 
        client.query('INSERT INTO "testSchema".logintable (id, name) VALUES ($1, $2)', [06, 'Ganesh'], function(err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error("\nError : " + err);
                    res.status(400).send(err);
                } else {
                    console.log("1 record inserted");
                    res.status(200).send(result.rows);
                }
            });
```